# Update progress bar without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have two php pages. page.php and loader.php. Loader.php pulls data from mysql to fill a progress bar and page.php contains a function to refresh loader.php every second. It works but it's rather ugly because you can see the css animation resetting every second.

I would prefer having the loading bar html in page.php along with all the other html for my page but A) how do I get the vars from loader.php into page.php and B) how do I update the div (or any object) on page.php without refreshing the page?

I looked into AJAX which seems like it can do what I want but I'm new to AJAX and programming in general. I'm already proud it is (somewhat) working to begin with.

page.php

```
<script>
var myTimer = null;

//executes a script that fills mysql with data
function fileExec() {
        $.ajax({
            url:"fileexec.php",
            type: "post"
        });
    startRefresh();
}

//Shows progress bar
function refreshData() {
  $('#container').load('loader.php');
}

function stopRefresh() {
  clearInterval(myTimer);
}

function startRefresh() {
 myTimer = setInterval(refreshData, 1000);
}

</script>
```

loader.php

```
<?php
//Code not shown sets up connection to mysql to pull progress
$progress1 = $row['progress'];
$script1 = $row['script'];

//Stop refresh after shell script has finished
if ($script1 == "stop") {
    echo "<script>";
    echo "stopRefresh();";
    echo "</script>";
}
?>

//Update progress bar with variable
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="progress-bar-wrapper">
        <div class="progress-bar">
            <div id="myBar" class="progress-bar-fill in-progress" style="height:10px;width:<?php echo $progress1; ?>%"></div>
         </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just return the value in the php, not the HTML. Then do something like `function refreshData() {
  $.post("loader.php",function(data) { $('#myBar').width(data);
})`

Comment: How do I specify which var(s) to retrieve from loader.php? I have multiple vars. I assume the latter part of the code updates the div with the new value.

Answer (score 2):

Update it using js:

```
$.post("loader.php", {
        function: "getProgress"
        }, function(data) {
            progress = JSON.parse(data);
            //use progress to change your bar with js
        });
```

And in the php:

```
switch ($_POST['function']) {
    case 'getProgress':
        getProgress();
    break;
}
function getProgress() {
    //get the progress state
    echo json_encode($progress);
}
```

Comment: I had to declare $progress as a global var and only use echo globalvar along with @mplungjan code for updating the div to make it work.

Is it possible to have another action besides just echo? I tried adding my conditional to trigger stopRefresh() but that did not work. Is there any way I can trigger a function on page.php if progress or script match a certain value from that same piece of ajax?

Comment: Yes as shown above by function: "getProgress" in js 
and 

switch ($_POST['function']) {
    case 'getProgress':
        getProgress();
    break;
} in php

Comment: You mean add another function below getProgress(); so case 'getProgress': getProgress; getSomeOtherFunction; break;?

Comment: Oh sorry I not read your Question correctly. Yes just check the value and add another function call inside getProgress() just like in normal PHP.